# Get aggregate function message when I add a EXIST clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which works fine:

```
Select 
SUM(CASE
    WHEN MethodId NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END) Total
 FROM pll_data
```

Next, I need to check if data exist in another table for the same `MethodId`. I get the following error (Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
)  when I add the `EXISTS` clause that preferences another `table`:

```
  SELECT 
  SUM(CASE
   WHEN 
    EXISTS(Select 1 from pll_dataSys pp WHERE pp.PNum = p.PNum AND pp.MethodID IN (1,2,3)) OR  -- I added this line of code
     MethodId NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END) Total
FROM pll_data p
```

NOTE: I get the following error when I add the `EXISTS` clause:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE
   WHEN ISNULL(result,0)=1 OR
      MethodId NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END) Total
FROM pll_data p 
 OUTER APPLY 
 ( Select TOP 1 1 as result 
     from pll_dataSys pp 
      WHERE pp.PNum = p.PNum AND pp.MethodID 
   IN (1,2,3)) A
```

Comment: Thank you. I still need to capture 1 or 0 for Total. I cannot do it with the OUTER APPLY the way you have it.

Comment: `EXISTS` -> `Select  top(1) 1 ..`

Comment: @Serg Still get the same message after I do  Select top(1) 1 FROM

Comment: @NatePet , I mean how the `outer apply` in the asnwer should implement `exists` to prevent excessive rows to be counted.

Comment: Hello, I have a slightly different query. If you can assist with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003168/case-statement-but-subquery-not-working-using-aggregate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can left join with `pp` with the criteria that you specified and check it against `null` in your `case`-`when`. To protect against duplicates, you can ensure that `pp` is unique by excluding all other `pp` lines for each result record:

```
  SELECT 
  SUM(CASE
   WHEN 
    NOT (pp.Num IS NULL) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   ELSE 0
  END) Total
FROM pll_data p
LEFT JOIN pll_dataSys pp
ON (p.PNum = pp.PNum AND pp.MethodID IN (1,2)) OR pp.MethodId NOT IN (1, 2)
LEFT JOIN pll_dataSys pp_not_existent
ON ((p.PNum = pp_not_existent.PNum AND pp_not_existent.MethodID IN (1,2)) OR pp_not_existent.MethodId NOT IN (1, 2)) AND pp.pp_id < pp_not_existent.pp_id
WHERE pp_not_existent.pp_IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does the other answer posted do the same thing?

Comment: @NatePet frankly I did not test the other annswer. My answer applies a LEFT JOIN to the potential record which may or may not exist and the other left join accopanied with the where ensures that if it happens to exist, then a single record is taken into account. And then I count the number of records who had at least such a pair. This type of logic is something I regularly apply with great success. The pattern of LEFT JOIN foo nonexistent ON ... WHERE nonexistent.id is null is something frequently needed.